# how to concate all the members id from that mongodb collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named group on the **mongoDb** database . The collection includes 2 or more object and each object contains an array named **members** . what is the best possible and efficient way to concate and get all the members data from the database. what would be the **mongoDB** query ?

my collection looks like

```
[

    {
        id: ObjcetId("15215252"),
        groupName: "travellers of Bangladesh",
        members: ["1","2","3"]
    },
    {
        id: ObjcetId("32643724362"),
        groupName: "People from Bangladesh",
        members: ["4","5","6"]
    }
]
```

and i Want just this exact data

```
members: ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use aggregations

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$group` to reconstruct the array

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$members" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      members: { $push: "$members" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bJYWXNvhrV4)**

Comment: I tried this exact way before, and when i run it from postman, i get this Json data in return
`[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "members": [
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d51",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d58",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d56",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d51",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d58",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d56"
        ]
    }
]`

so is there any way to return just exact array without the object inside of an array?

Comment: You will receive key:value pair. What you can do is, you can assign to a varible `var data=getMambers(); console.log(data.members)` . This will be good practice if you need to send any other data also, you can easily get